# Functional tests on Symfony 2 - issue with the default autoload.php.dist

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I have been trying to run FunctionalTest which extends the Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\WebTestCase with not so much success.

The issue is that:

1. the code in FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\app\AppKernel.php attempts to load autoload.php.dist in the framework bundle (not the one in the app/).
2. And autoload.php.dist then tries to load vendor\autoload.php which does not exist within this path.

If I remove the autoload.php.dist  in the FrameworkBundle then everything is fine, but I want to avoid doing that because each time I do composer update I will then have to remove that specific fine.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

The exact error from the console is posted below for your information:

> Configuration read from D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\app\phpunit.xml.
>   dist
>
> 1. require_once() called at [D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\sym
>      fony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\app\AppKernel.p
>      hp:26]
> 2. require_once(D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\symfony\symfony\
>      src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\app\AppKernel.php)
>      called at 
>      [D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bun
>      dle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\Functional\WebTestCase.php:47]
>
> Fatal error: main(): Failed opening required
>   'D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\symfony\symfony/vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\demo\vendor\symfony\sym
>   fony\autoload.php.dist on line 9

The test class simply extends WebTestCase with the setUp looks like this:

```
static::$kernel = static::createKernel(array('test_case'));
static::$kernel->boot();
$this->containter = static::$kernel->getContainer();
```

Comment: I just ran a test on my unix machine and it's working.  Don't have a windows machine handy.  You just have MyTest extends WebTestCase?  Have you gotten tests to run under xampp before?  I use xampp at home and have not had a problem.  What version of symfony?

Comment: All my tests are running fine, but those are just basic unit tests, this is the first time I extends WebTestCase. You are right, MyTest simply extends WebTestCase, also I simly get the container in the setUp. Let me add that in the question

Comment: Are you using the supplied phpunit.xml file either with phpunit -C or just by running phpunit in the app directory?  Did you make any tweaks to phpunit.xml?  There is a bootstrap line in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay.  I see the problem.  You are extending from Tests\Functional\WebTestCase.  That is actually a test for testing the WebTestCase.  You want to extend from Test\WebTestCase.

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class PersonRepositoryTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function testProject()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $manager = $client->getContainer()->get('cerad_person.manager');
```

And you might want to get one or two working using the $client line shown above.  All the setup stuff can be a bit tricky.